# what is the problem with the code. It is storing empty matrix except for few places it is printing ","

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.read_csv("D:\PHD\obranking\demo.csv")

Mat = np.empty((300, 300), dtype=str)
for i in range(1,5502):
    for j in range(0,300):
        for k in range(0,300):
            if df1['label'][j] != df1['label'][k]:
                if df1[df1.columns[i]][j] != df1[df1.columns[i]][k]:
                    Mat[j][k] = Mat[j][k] + "," + df1.columns[i]
np.save("D:\PHD\obranking\MatDemo", Mat)
```

PS: `df1.columns[i]` is having values as string. It is not empty in every case

Comment: Add in your sample data and expected output, you should never need to nest 3 levels of for loops with ranges for a simple string concatenation.

Comment: With the `str` dtype, `Mat` is a 'U1' array, that is, each element can only have 1 character.

Comment: @hpaulj then what needs to be used as data type inorder to store string instead of the charracter. I mean how can i modiify to store a string as an array element

Comment: @hpaulj i tried to modify my code based on your input. i used dtype ='object' to store a large concatenation of string' . Here is my code

Comment: ``` import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.read_csv("D:\PHD\obranking\demo.csv")

Mat = np.empty((300, 300), dtype='object')
for i in range(1,5502):
    for j in range(0,300):
        for k in range(0,300):
            if df1['label'][j] != df1['label'][k]:
                if df1[df1.columns[i]][j] != df1[df1.columns[i]][k]:
                    Mat[j][k] += '#'
                    Mat[j][k] += df1.columns[i]
np.save("D:\PHD\obranking\MatDemo", Mat)```

Comment: @hpaulj but getting this error now :  Mat[j][k] += '#'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Answer (score 1):

Your original dtype:

```
In [16]: arr = np.empty((2,), dtype=str)                                        
In [17]: arr                                                                    
Out[17]: array(['', ''], dtype='<U1')    # str is equivalent to U1 - 1 char string
```

Trying to add a string:

```
In [18]: arr[0] += ','+'foobar'                                                 
In [19]: arr                                                                    
Out[19]: array([',', ''], dtype='<U1')
```

There is only space for 1 char, so we just get the comma.  There have been complaints about this truncation; some think numpy should either raise an error, or expand the dtype.

Better, let's start with a longer dtype:

```
In [20]: arr = np.empty((2,), dtype='U10')                                      
In [21]: arr                                                                    
Out[21]: array(['', ''], dtype='<U10')    
In [22]: arr[0] += ','+'foobar'                                                 
In [23]: arr                                                                    
Out[23]: array([',foobar', ''], dtype='<U10')    # now we see the full addition
In [24]: arr[0] += ','+'foobar'                                                 
In [25]: arr                                                                    
Out[25]: array([',foobar,fo', ''], dtype='<U10')  # but still get truncation
```

Your next try:

```
In [26]: arr = np.empty((2,), dtype=object)                                     
In [27]: arr                                                                    
Out[27]: array([None, None], dtype=object)   # note the initial fill value

In [28]: arr[0] += ','+'foobar'                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-2c5ca97a0fa9> in <module>
----> 1 arr[0] += ','+'foobar'

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

In both of these cases, if you had looked at `Mat` at the start, or tested a small example as I've shown, you'd might have seen the problem.  Start with small test cases, examining values at each step.  No point in trying to work with a 300x300 case if it doesn't work for one case.

But if we start with a blank string (this is different from the `U1` or `U10` numpy string type):

```
In [29]: arr[0] = ''                                                            
In [30]: arr                                                                    
Out[30]: array(['', None], dtype=object)
In [31]: arr[0] += ','+'foobar'                                                 
In [32]: arr                                                                    
Out[32]: array([',foobar', None], dtype=object)
In [33]: arr[0] += ','+'foobar'                                                 
In [34]: arr                                                                    
Out[34]: array([',foobar,foobar', None], dtype=object)
```

`pandas` has chosen to bypass `numpy` string dtypes, and instead stores strings as objects, Python strings.  The `numpy` approach is more efficient, memory wise, at least if the strings are all about the same size.  But if they vary widely in size, or need to grow like this, the object dtype is better.

In your case you start with `pandas` and its object strings, and are adding large but variable number of them to the array. Sticking with the object dtype is probably best.  But be ware of the initial `None`.

Another approach is to collect the strings in a list:

```
In [35]: arr[1]=[]                                                              
In [36]: arr                                                                    
Out[36]: array([',foobar,foobar', list([])], dtype=object)
In [37]: arr[1].append('foobar')                                                
In [38]: arr[1].append('foobar')                                                
In [39]: arr                                                                    
Out[39]: array([',foobar,foobar', list(['foobar', 'foobar'])], dtype=object)
In [40]: arr[1]=','.join(arr[1])                                                
In [41]: arr                                                                    
Out[41]: array([',foobar,foobar', 'foobar,foobar'], dtype=object)
```

List append is more efficient than string concatenate, and `join` does a cleaner job of putting the delimiter *between* strings.

An object dtype array is close to a list in nature and processing.  It has none of fast processing that we see with numeric dtypes.